# Oracle's VirtualBox and keyloggers

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, xubuntu, malware

So, I have installed Windows 7 in Oracle's VirtualBox (5.0.8) and I would like to know if the Windows 7 software (including viruses and malware) is able in the default VirtualBox settings access the keyboard input outside of the VirtualBox.

I mean, if, for example, a keylogger inside my Windows 7 VM is able to catch the keypresses in the Firefox installed on my default Xubuntu installation (host OS) that is running/hosting the VirtualBox.

Comment: Could fit [security.se] as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With default settings, software in a Windows 7 guest would not be able to access the keyboard input from outside of Virtualbox such as the host or another running guest. Access to the host OS resources would have to be permitted explicitly in some way to permit the guest control.

However, human error can always sabotage the implicit security controls. Consider typing while the guest is being granted access by accident, like while you think you are typing into the host but the guest retained or attained control back. This can happen by a non-observant user or inadequate UI cues as to the state of the current environment. E.g. Control of the input resources could be handed to VM by an inadvertent hotkey trigger and the user not noticing. If Virtualbox Extensions have been installed, this could also occur by bumping the mouse or brushing the touchpad with focus-follows-mouse active.

However, once you move beyond the default settings, there are many potential gotchas that would compromise your host's security or a user's privacy by way of indirect keyboard input capture. For example:

- depending on how the guest network has been setup, it could be possible to sniff network traffic for traffic visited by the host, thereby indirectly reading what you typed in Firefox's address bar.
- if shared clipboard access has been enabled, the guest could read all information you copy to the host's clipboard.

If the question were expanded to outside the domain of just guest keylogger access, there are a myriad of [security issues](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch13.html) that should be accounted for based on what resources you share.

Comment: "If Virtualbox Extensions have been installed"
But what matters is that there is an API, theoretically some software of the guest could access all of the API by itself and the host would not have to explicitly allow it.

Comment: @phk Can you post a link where such issue is dicussed. Can't find any. Thank you.